# Calling a component from index.html in Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, components

In my app there's no `App.vue` component assigned to the `#app` element. Instead, in my `index.html`, I have a `<router-view>` element which displays some `Home.vue` component by default or whatever other component depending on the route.

However I want to display a certain component (informing about user online status) at all times regardless of the current route. But how can I achieve this if it's not possible to call a component from index.html? Or is it possible?

**index.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head><meta charset="utf-8"></head>
  <body>
    <div id="app">
      <!-- Component handling user status (connected / not connected) would go here -->
      <router-view></router-view>
    </div>
    <script src="dist/build.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you provide an sample example in [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place your component above `<router-view>` (where the comment indicates `<!-- Component handling user status would go here -->`):

```
<div id="app">
  <user-presence-status></user-presence-status>
  <router-view></router-view>
</div>
```

Be sure to include the component definition when mounting the root component, as shown in the following example:

```
import UserPresenceStatus from '@/components/UserPresenceStatus';

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  compnents: {
    UserPresenceStatus
  }
);
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/1q0j4y2jq)